# Docker image for Rshiny app that uses python scripts too

Tags: python, docker, py-shiny

I'm new to Docker and I want to create an image in orde rto deploy a shiny app that sources python scripts using "reticulate" package.

Is there a place where I can start building this Docker image or build on top of some existing images.

I Can provide the scripts that I use for this app.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter's docker-stacks repo has some good examples: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks

For R: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/r-notebook/Dockerfile

For Python/Julia/R: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile

I figure these are overkill for what you need, but they might be a helpful reference